# Fetching a Single Phone Number from a contact in Contacts Book which is having multiple numbers saved

Tags: android, android-contacts

I need to ask a user for a contact number to make a call. On Button Click the User should be directly redirected to Contacts Book and the user can select a Phone Number. Following is the Source Code what I am using now.

```
Button buttonReadContact;
TextView textPhone;
final int RQS_PICKCONTACT = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonReadContact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.readcontact);
    textPhone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.phone);



    buttonReadContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Start activity to get contact
            final Uri uriContact = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
            Intent intentPickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uriContact);
            startActivityForResult(intentPickContact, RQS_PICKCONTACT);
        }});

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == RQS_PICKCONTACT){
            Uri returnUri = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);

            if(cursor.moveToNext()){
                int columnIndex_ID = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
                String contactID = cursor.getString(columnIndex_ID);

                int columnIndex_HASPHONENUMBER = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
                String stringHasPhoneNumber = cursor.getString(columnIndex_HASPHONENUMBER);

                if(stringHasPhoneNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                    Cursor cursorNum = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactID,
                            null,
                            null);

                    //Get the first phone number
                    if(cursorNum.moveToNext()){
                        int columnIndex_number = cursorNum.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                        String stringNumber = cursorNum.getString(columnIndex_number);
                        textPhone.setText(stringNumber);
                    }

                }else{
                    textPhone.setText("NO Phone Number");
                }


            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now the issue is I can only select one number from a contact which is having multiple Phone Numbers saved.

I need to do this as in Skype Application. When the User select a contact which is having multiple contacts, from the Contacts Book itself it should ask the User to choose the number. Please help me to do it.

Comment: Sorry but not getting your issue, what is the issue in selecting one number from multiple phone numbers? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Now when I am selecting Contact with multiple numbers saved it is not asking me which phone number I need to select. It is directly taking the first phone number

Comment: In skype application I have seen that, when we select a contact from contacts book, it will show a popup window for contacts which is having multiple numbers. From that popup window we can select the number we need. The popup window is not loaded from the application. But from the contacts book itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this code to open the Contacts and allow the user to select a single contact, then parse the result to display the contact name, phone number and thumbnail photo. In the example below, the members mName, mPhoneNumber, and mContactImage are already defined.

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start an activity to pick a single contact (ACTION_PICK)
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                // Show only contacts with phone numbers
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                // Start the Contacts activity
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
        }
    });
```

Parse the results in onActivityResult().

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_CONTACT :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI};
                Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactData, projection, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int nameIdx = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int phoneNumberIdx = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                int photoIdx = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI);
                String name = c.getString(nameIdx);
                String phoneNumber = c.getString(phoneNumberIdx);
                String photo = c.getString(photoIdx);
                if (photo == null) {
                    // If no photo then substitute a dummy image
                    mContactImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
                } else {
                    // Display the contact photo
                    final Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(photo);
                    mContactImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
                }
                if (name == null) {
                    name = "No Name";
                }
                mName.setText(name);
                mPhoneNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
                c.close();

                // Now you have the phone number

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I think this answers your question.